# What are the differences between turbojet and turbofan (low and high by-pass ratio) in the graph of thrust relative to speed?

Tags: jet-engine

What are the curves of thrust relative to velocity of the turbojet, low-bypass turbofan and high-bypass turbofan engines from static thrust to Mach 4 generally. Approximation is okay as long it has any Mach or other speed values. Graph is preferred, because most graphs of these values I have found are starting at around Mach 0.5 or completely without any axes description.

Mostly I want to know is what difference there is at speeds of 0 to Mach 1 in these three engine types.

(I have wrote question containing around 400 words so I reduced it to this after getting suggestion its too long)

Comment: Fixed @RalphJ, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Much better, thanks!